# Handling empty resultset from a query

Tags: scriptella

I have two databases with the same structure and I want to compare records between databases. The records in second database are copied from the first database, but the copying process sometime doesn't work and in the first database in one table I have more records than in the same table in the second database. So I want to know which records from the first database doesn't exists in the second database. I have tried with something like that:

```
<etl>
<connection id="db1" driver="auto"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db" user="user"
    password="xxx"
    classpath="C:/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.jar" />
<connection id="db2" driver="auto"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/db" user="user"
    password="xxx"
    classpath="C:/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.jar" />
<connection id="text" driver="text" />
<query connection-id="db1">
    SELECT * FROM table;
    <query connection-id="db2">
        SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id';
        <script connection-id="text">
            sometext, $rownum
        </script>
    </query>
</query>
</etl>
```

The problem is, when the result of the query against db2 is empty the script is not executed.

How to solve this problem?

Regards,
Jacek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use count to check the actual number of records. In this case resultset will always return one row. Example:

```
<query connection-id="db1">
    SELECT * FROM table;
    <query connection-id="db2">
        SELECT count(id) as CNT FROM table WHERE id = ?id;
        <!-- The script is executed ONLY IF number of results is zero -->
        <script connection-id="text" if="CNT==0">
            No matching record for id $id
        </script>
    </query>
</query>
```

Comment: Great! It works! The problem is I don't understand the visibility of variables in nested queries and scripts. Where can I find a good description?

Comment: I afraid there is no simple explanation of how variable contexts works. I'll make a post on the scriptella.wordpress.com if I finally get some time for this (you know OS folks suck at properly documenting things). But in few words the idea is simple - when a query is executed, for each returned row, it calls nested scripts(or other query elements) and column values of the current row are available as variables to these **inner** elements. You can include queries into other queries, but the logic is the same all parent columns are available to children only, but not siblings.

Answer (score 0):

Probably he doesn't need the if condition, because his problem is the script wasn't executed ;)

Comment: I assume you are replying to my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15661587/1129542). The script was not executed because there were zero results. With COUNT(*) there always be ONE row containing number of records found.

Comment: Yes, this **if** is very important for, this gives a possibility to insert a logic in etl.xml file.

Comment: Oh understood, i thought the original intention is something like below:

`...
SELECT count(id) as CNT FROM table WHERE id = ?id;
<script connection-id="text">
  Number of matching record for id $id: ?CNT
</script>
...
`